# In the .NET framework, how is an object's field address located at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net

In the .NET framework, how is an object's field address located at runtime? Is there a fixed offset applied on the address of the object?

Comment: Well, yes: fields are a fixed offset from an object header, but: what is the use-case here? What are you actually trying to do? For example, `ref someObj.someField` captures the field address as a managed interior pointer, which *is* the address (the only "safe" version of the address, at least; you can also get an unmanaged pointer, but that is problematic from a GC perspective)

Comment: Yes.  Debug > Windows > Assembly provides that insight.